# NSRange changes itself inside for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrange, nsexception, nsrangeexception

I have an NSDictionary of NSRange objects, with keys for their index in the array. I am attempting to use each of these ranges to create substrings of a larger string, and place each of these substrings in the array. I basically have this completed, but the NSRange is mysteriously changing it's value in the code, causing it to crash and throw an exception. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray*subStringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(id key in aDict){
            NSRange* range = CFBridgingRetain([aDict objectForKey:key]);
            NSLog(@"This is a single range: %@",range);
            //Range is changed here somehow
            NSString* aSubString = [self.content substringWithRange:*range];
            NSLog(@"%@",aSubString);
            [subStringArray addObject:aSubString];
        }
```

My Log output looks like this:

```
This is a single range: NSRange: {1874, 72}
2014-06-17 20:07:30.100 testApp[8027:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     
'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {4318599072, 4} out of bounds; string length 5562'
```

Comment: Several problems: 1) You can't directly store an `NSRange` in a dictionary (or other collection). 2) `NSRange` is a `struct`, not a class. Don't use it with pointers. 3) Don't use `CFBridgingRetain` with a `struct`. Wrap the `NSRange` in an `NSValue` to use it with collections.

Comment: @maddy, you should flesh out your comment a little and submit it as an answer. You've touched on most of the things that are wrong with the OP's code, so you deserve the "accepted answer" rep points.

Comment: I agree 100%. Thanks rmaddy. I'll gladly check the box if you submit this as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By popular demand :)

The main issue with your code is that you are directly storing an `NSRange` struct in your dictionary. You can't do this. You must wrap the `NSRange` in an `NSValue` to store it in the dictionary.

To add the `NSRange` you can do:

```
NSRange range = ... // some range
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithRange:range];
dict[someKey] = value;
```

Then your posted code becomes:

```
for (id key in aDict) {
    NSValue *value = aDict[key];
    NSRange range = [value rangeValue];
    NSLog(@"This is a single range: %@",range);
    //Range is changed here somehow
    NSString* aSubString = [self.content substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@",aSubString);
    [subStringArray addObject:aSubString];
}
```